# How correctly traslate into English "тестовое задание"?

Tags: перевод

For example when you go to get new job, you will be given a "тестовое задание". How to translate this combination of words into English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of question is definitely off-topic on this site.  However to help you out, the right translation is *test assignment* or *trial assignment*. I work as a manager in the software development organisation in England.  When I look for new people, part of the selection process is *technical test*.

Once a candidate is hired, they will typically be given some *test assignments* (in my previous job we called them *trial assignments*) to confirm that they can really do the work expected of them.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate **"тестовое задание"** as **"an aptitude test (for job applicants)"**.

Answer (score 1):

We call it just 'test task', esp for IT-related positions